# PHP/MYSQL: Multiple values using same identifying number

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write data from an invoice into 2 tables
table 1 is the invoices table
it contains:

`invoice_id account sales purchase_date`

then a second table invoice_items it contains the information about each line in the invoice.

```
id  invoice_id  item    description     quantity    price   amount
```

Basically now I am checking to see if the id exists and if it does I check if the line id exists and if it doesn't it adds the information for the invoice if the id exists it checks to see if the line id exists

```
$checkin = mysql_query("
SELECT `id`
FROM `invoices`
WHERE `invoices`.`id` =$invoice_id
");

if (mysql_num_rows($checkin) == 1) 
{
  $updatememocount ++;

  mysql_query("UPDATE `invoices`  SET `invoices`.`INV_ID` = '".$invid."'WHERE `invoices`.`id` =$invoice_id ") or die("load1 -" . mysql_error());

  // check line id
  $checklineid = mysql_query("SELECT `Line_ID` from `invoice_items` WHERE `Line_ID` = '$lineid'") or die("load1 -" . mysql_error());
  if (mysql_num_rows($checklineid) == 0) 
  {
    $insertlinecount ++;
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `invoice_items` (invoice_id, item, description, quantity, price, amount, Line_ID) VALUES ('".$invoice_id."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($row['3'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($row['4'])."', '".$row['9']."', '".$row['7']."', '".$row['5']."', '".$row['14']."' ) ") or die("load1 -" . mysql_error());
  } 
}
else
{
  // makes new invoice entry and enters the line item information for the first line.
}
```

Data sample this is how the data comes in

```
Date    Invoice_Id    Item           Description             Price    Amount   Customer_ID   Line_ID
05/12/12  1234        something     whatever somthing  is     15        15       2255          123
05/12/12  1234        Another_thing  Whatever that is         25        25       2255          124
```

Comment: Why not use an autoincrement value for the invoice id?

Comment: the invoice id's come with the data.

Comment: I was tentatively thinking that I could could count all the instances then loop through and write till the counter = 0 but I don;t know how to write that.

Comment: I don't know if it is just myself but I'm a bit confused. `I am checking to see if the id exists and if it does I check if the line id exists and if it doesn't it adds the information for the invoice if the id exists it checks to see if the line id exists` ??? Be more precise and don't worry about big questions, the more information it has, the better will be the answers.

Comment: I  think I got it. I will just treat them separately. I will check if it exists in the invoice table and if it doesn't i will insert. Then I will check if it is in the line item table and if not i will insert. sounds simple enough. I was trying to validate the whole thing throught the invoice table.

Answer (score 0):

look this example, on [duplicate key insert](http://webguru.org/2007/12/18/lamp/mysql-on-duplicate-key-insert/)

```
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(UserID) FROM configuration WHERE UserID='SomeUser'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
    $aResult = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $iRecordExists = ($aResult[0]>0?1:0);
}

   if ($iRecordExists>0) {
   //make the insert with another ID
    }
    else {
    //do an insert
    $sql = "INSERT INTO configuration SET someField='someValue', UserID='SomeUser'";
    mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: this is pretty close to what i was thinking. How do i count the number of instances in an array. I am reading this information in from a csv file.